# Edit and delete a row on a table based on a id from another table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

with the code that is provided by Visual Studio from the scaffolding i get the delete and the edit controller from a model automaticaly, but what if i need to edit/delete a row from database x based on a row from database y based on the id i explain it via code:

**Controller Edit what i did**

```
var despesaUtilizador = db.SaldoUtilizadores.Where(x => x.despesaId == despesa.DespesaId).Where(x => x.ApplicationUserId == userId).First();
        despesaUtilizador.valor = despesa.DespesaValor;
        despesaUtilizador.data = despesa.Data;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(despesaUtilizador).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(despesa).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

i did a query to the database SaldoUtilizadores to get the row that matches the id that is send to the controller and then i try to edit that row, i just dont know if i am doing that the right way if someone can explain it

**Controller Delete**

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Despesa despesa = db.Despesas.Find(id);
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var despesaUtilizador = db.SaldoUtilizadores.Where(x => x.despesaId == id).Where(x => x.ApplicationUserId == userId).First();
        db.Despesas.Remove(despesa);
        db.SaldoUtilizadores.Remove(despesaUtilizador);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

int the delete i try to do the same, it dont work either :/

Comment: I don't see multiple databases here. You're only utilizing one context.

Comment: sorry i didnt mean databases, i mean classes from a database

Comment: So what is the actual problem? Are you getting an exception? What's not working, and more importantly *how* is it not working?

Comment: i get this exception "Sequence contains no elements"

Answer (score 0):

> i get this exception "Sequence contains no elements"

That comes from using `First()`. If there's no matching elements, it will raise that exception because there's no "first" item it can return.

You should always use `FirstOrDefault()` unless you're 100% sure there's actually items in a collection. `FirstOrDefault()` will return null if nothing is matched, rather than raising an exception. You can then check for the presence of null and handle accordingly.

If you think that there really should be something being returned, then you need to figure out why that's not the case. Inspect the data in your database and make sure the query you're issuing lines up with what's actually there.

Comment: the problem here is: i dont get a exception i am 100% sure that it must go that way, the problem that i get is that when i edit, the list with all my expenses dont appear on the view and if i go to my database i have them all there :S

Comment: Then there's some issue with your query. If I had to guess, I would say the property you think is your foreign key is not actually being utilized as the foreign key (entity is improperly configured). Post your entity classes, and that might be able to shed some light on the issue.